# Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run mapreduce job on two node cluster. I am getting the following error
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.

I read through some posts which say it is due to problem in /etc/hosts

my /etc/hosts in master looks like this.( Also, master itself is a slave):
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   xyz
10.140.169.41 master
10.140.169.38 slave

/etc/hosts in slave looks like this

127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.1.1      abc
10.140.169.41 master
10.140.169.38 slave

I have turned off the firewall

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you solve this at all? I'm facing the same issue, but only when I have multiple files in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling is the phase when intermediate data is being transferred from mapper to reducer. You have not mentioned what Map Reduce properties you have set for your code to run, but I can suggest you to try out setting following properties:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent</name>
    <value>0.20</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
```

If you need the description about how can we calculate the buffer input percentage have a look at this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6447/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are your hosts actually named 'master' and 'slave'? Make sure the entries in your `/etc/hosts` file match the name of the host, i.e. the output of `hostname`.

Comment: what is `name of the box`?

Answer (score 0):

As [Neha mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47684180/3127174) during the shuffle phase data needs to be transferred within the hadoop cluster. You should therefore check the log output for you data nodes, name nodes, and secondary nodes in the cluster that might be causing trouble transferring this data.

For example, I had an issue where a kerberos principle was not properly being mapped to the hdfs system user due to a misconfiguration in my core-site.yml file.

In another example, I was receiving the error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```